# Any redis module available to be able to perform this LINQ logic within redis

Tags: c#, linq, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a redisjson server that has a single database.  I extract all data from that database into `union` which an `IQueryable<IPosition>`.  I then have this following `linq` logic.

```
var final = from t1 in union
                        join t2 in union on
                        new { t1.EventKey, t1.BetCategory, t1.CustomParticipant, t1.CustomLine } equals
                        new { t2.EventKey, t2.BetCategory, t2.CustomParticipant, t2.CustomLine }
                        where
                        t1.BetPosition != t2.BetPosition &&
                        (1 / t1.OddsDecimal + 1 / t2.OddsDecimal) < .985
                        select new
                        {
                            PositionId1 = t1.PositionId,
                            OddsDecimal1 = t1.OddsDecimal,
                            BetData1 = t1.BetData,
                            PositionId2 = t2.PositionId,
                            OddsDecimal2 = t2.OddsDecimal,
                            BetData2 = t2.BetData,
                            BetCategory = t1.BetCategory
                        };
```

I am wondering if it's possible to somehow perform this operation within the redis server.  It is taking 2000ms to return all data from the local redis server that has only 20k keys.

```
var sportEventRet = _redis.GetDatabase(1).JsonMultiGetAsync(keysList.ToArray());
```

This is part of the logic I use to extract my data from my local redis server and it takes 1500ms alone and I don't believe I have any other options to return data other than this function, so my only option is to try and perform the LINQ logic on redis.  I am trying to get the output of my logic in under 600ms.

I have looked into redisearch however I can't figure out how to do a join which is required.  The explanation of my LINQ logic is I have a bunch of `Positions` and I want to find all positions that have the same multi-part key `t1.EventKey, t1.BetCategory, t1.CustomParticipant, t1.CustomLine` but then

```
t1.BetPosition != t2.BetPosition && (1 / t1.OddsDecimal + 1 / t2.OddsDecimal) < .985
```

The linq logic runs in sub 100ms, however the big issue with keeping it in LINQ is the massive time it takes to get the data out of redis (2000ms with 1500ms alone on the `JsonMultiGetAsync` which I don't believe I have any alternatives for.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is if your using RedisJSON and other Redis stack servers go with **`redis-om-dotnet`- Object mapping for Redis and .NET linq support**
https://github.com/redis/redis-om-dotnet